# I need to print an URL that changes according to date

Tags: python, date, request

My print function returns the correct URL, but it also returns "None" at the very end, screwing the whole procces when I try to use it in a request.

Code is:

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()



import requests
todayurl = print('https://www.bling.com.br/Api/v3/nfe?pagina=1&limite=100&situacao=1&tipo=1&dataEmissaoInicial=', today, '&dataEmissaoFinal=', today, sep='')
print(todayurl)
```

Returns:

```
> & C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe k:/code/get_nfe_then_post_on_slack.py
https://www.bling.com.br/Api/v3/nfe?pagina=1&limite=100&situacao=1&tipo=1&dataEmissaoInicial=2023-08-18&dataEmissaoFinal=2023-08-18
**None**
PS K:\code>
```

How do I get rid of that "None" at the end? I'm trying to automate a get request and then a message to slack with some of the contents, but the request won't work with the None at the end.

Tried to use date.today() function to return the current date so I could insert it on the correct part of the URL. Although it returned the URL correctly it also returned None at the end, making the script unable to run the request properly.

Answer (score 0):

`print` is a function that display a value and returns `None`, which is the value that gets saved in `todayurl`.
To assign your formatted string to a variable, the easiest solution  is to use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

```
from datetime import date
today = date.today()

todayurl = f"https://www.bling.com.br/Api/v3/nfe?pagina=1&limite=100&situacao=1&tipo=1&dataEmissaoInicial{today}&dataEmissaoFinal={today}"
print(todayurl)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm! I'm too new to upvote you, but if I could, I would! Thanks again!!